# [BUG]rodeo can not process loops in python

Tags: python, ide

I've been using a really cool idea for python rodeo. Basically the interface looks like Rstudio. However, it doesn't recognize loop by giving the following error "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing".

And when I paste the same command on my python shell and it works just fine.

Anyone know how to debug it?